# SelectOption Numbering

Tags: apex

So my question is probably simple. I want to put a value (numbers or text) by a select list option. Now I know I can do this:

```
options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada'));
```

Right now I have this:

```
Value.add (new selectOption(v.id, String.valueOf(v.CreatedDate)))
```

So this returns the id of the field as well as the label, which is the created date. I want to stick a text right before the String value. I've tried inserting a 'Change Request' into the select Option but no dice..any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not getting it clearly, do you need to append the text 'Change Request' with your date value? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yeah, basically formatting errors. In essence I would like it to look like:

Change Request ...(Date value)
Change Request ...(Date value)
Change Request ...(Date value)

I've already got the list working and populating the dropdown. I just want to add that text to it. Most of the examples online just reference a value and a label for the selectlist, and I'm trying to add a text value to that select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix a static text like this

```
Value.add(new selectOption(v.id, 'Change Request - ' + String.valueOf(v.CreatedDate)));
```